# Does Hibernate close the reference cursor automatically?

Tags: hibernate, plsql

I have defined a PL/SQL stored procedure which returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findByName
(  res OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, 
   vName IN emp.name%type  ) AS
BEGIN
  OPEN res FOR
    SELECT * FROM emp WHERE name = vName;
END findByName;
```

Then, I map the returned cursor to a Hibernate entity.

```
....
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(name = "findByName", query = "call findByName(?, :vName)", callable = true, resultClass = Employee.class)
@Table(name = "EMP", schema = "WEBUI")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {
....
```

This is a DAO method that calls the stored procedure.

```
....
public Employee findByName(final String name) {
    Session session = factory.getSession();
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findByName");
    query.setString("vName", name);
    return (Employee) query.uniqueResult();      
}
....
```

This is what I would do if I were calling the stored procedure from PL/SQL code.

```
DECLARE
    emp_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    emp_rec emp_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    findByName 
    (  res => emp_cursor,
       vName => 'Timothy Jones');
    FETCH emp_cursor
        INTO emp_rec;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_rec.name);
    CLOSE emp_cursor; -- close the cursor
END;
```

I would like to highlight the fact that it is necessary to close the `emp_cursor`, somehow. Otherwise, memory leak would have been caused.

My question is:
How does Hibernate handle this? Does it automatically close the cursor after the Employee object has been retrieved or does the programmer have to close it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this link more or less answers my question:
http://www.zugiart.com/2010/08/handling-oracle-cursors-in-jdbc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way to close this cursor. Hibernate reference wants you to return a cursor when using a stored procedure for a query.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#sp_query

My guess is that hibernate translates the returned cursor into a ResultSet used to iterate over the query results. It would be a serious hibernate bug if the ResultSet remained opened.
Anyway this ResultSet is in the worst case closed when the database connection pool recycles/closes the jdbc connection/statement.

Comment: I think this is a very thought answer. Thanks for answering.